# How can I clone a node, copying the data but not the event handlers?

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.8, jquery-clone

jQuery's `clone` function looks like this:

> .clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )
>
> **withDataAndEvents**: A Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the
>   elements.
>
> **deepWithDataAndEvents**: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all
>   children of the cloned element should be copied.

Both of these parameters affect `data` *and* `events`. Would it be possible to keep only the data, but not the events? Basically, my ideal `clone` function would look like this:

> .idealClone( [withData] [, withEvents ] [, deepWithData ] [, deepWithEvents ] )
>
> **withData**: A Boolean indicating
>   whether data should be copied along with the
>   elements.
>
> **withEvents**: A Boolean indicating
>   whether event handlers should be copied along with the
>   elements.
>
> **deepWithData**: A Boolean indicating whether data for all
>   children of the cloned element should be copied.
>
> **deepWithEvents**: A Boolean indicating whether event handlers for all
>   children of the cloned element should be copied.

Is there any way to acheive this?

NB I'm working with 1.8.1, but answers for all version are welcome

Comment: Can't you just use `clone()` and `unbind()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily extend the jQuery object with your ideal clone method, and use various combinations of [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data) and [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off) to keep only the things you want. Personally I think it's easy enough to just do:

```
// clones with data and events, then unbinds all events (bound with .on)
$(element).clone(true).off();
```

Comment: Won't that only remove those bound with `on()`?

Comment: @Ben Yes I believe so, thanks for the clarification. I haven't tried, but the docs suggest so.

Comment: All events are attached with `.on()` in the newer jQuery versions (I think >= 1.7). For example using `.click(handler)` is a shortcut for using `.on('click', handler)`, therefore, unless some method was attached using the deprecated `.bind()`, using `.off()` should be fine!

Comment: I tried that, but where `$(element).clone(true, true)` works fine, using `$(element).clone(true, true).off()` gives me an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'off'`.

Comment: @Shawn Be careful with your jQuery versions: [`off`](http://api.jquery.com/off) wasn't added til jQuery 1.7, so in earlier versions that error would be expected. You probably tested with different versions, causing the difficulty with reproducing it.

Comment: No, I'm using 1.8.1 in my own code and 1.8.3 in jsfiddle for testing. Both should have `off`.

Comment: Ok, I double-checked and even though I downloaded jquery 1.8.1, Drupal forces the use of 1.4.4. In this case, can I simply use `unbind()` and expect the same result?

Comment: @Shawn Event-handling was a lot more fragmented in the older versions (hence the transition to the unified api with `on`/`off` in newer versions). If there's no way to change versions, I would say just be careful about what kind of event handling code you use: for `delegate`, you use `undelegate`; for `live`, you use `die`; for `bind`, you use `unbind`. So, the simple answer is you have to undo whatever your specific code does :)